# Yii 1 define timestamp to clear assets files

Tags: caching, yii, assets

Now exist problem, because I modify `css` or `js` files users must clearing clear their browser cache to get newest changes. How to prevent this ? I think, that best way is define assets timestamp, `Yii` have something special for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I not understand for what is it. After deploy new version static to server you can clear assets folder. After this will be created new assets from last version files.